# Using package variable in OLE DB Source

Tags: ssis

In the Control Flow, I created a Execute SQL Task in SSIS.  In the General tab, under SQLStatement I am able to write my query.  Something like this:

```
select config_value from config_table where name ='ArchiveDays'
```

In the Parameter Mapping tab, I am able to create variable: `User::ConfigValue`

In the Result Set tab, I have the following:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12421846/ssis/result_Set.JPG]

I am able to run the Execute Data Flow Task without issue.

How can I check the value in the variable after I run the dataflow?

In the Control Flow, Data Flow task, I have a OLE DB Source, I try to use the variable created.  The query parses, but I get the following Error message.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12421846/ssis/error_msg2.JPG]

How to resolve?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you map parameters in SSIS. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx) is going to be helpful in your career and books online is the place to start.

Parameterization in an OLE DB Source is accomplished through the use of `?` which is an ordinal, zero-based replacement scheme.

Your query would need to be rewritten to use the parameters. And it should also be [re-written to not be lazy](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Something like

```
WHERE CAST(CreatedOn as date) < dateadd(DAY, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

And that is where you'd map in your `@User::carepro_ConfigValue`